# Tableau - Columns are hidden - how to fix

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau 10.1.1 version.

I have used 15 columns in my tableau worksheet, but I am able to see only 11 columns when I see the sheet. I am not able to see remaining 4 columns (it is hidden). I want to see all the columns in my sheet atleast with drag option below in the sheet.

Could you please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Tableau is not designed to display large spread sheet like tables as it is a data visualization tool and therefore, is not great for this.

You can increase the amount of columns viewable to a certain extent by going to Analysis-> Table Layout -> Advanced. Here in this pop up you can increase the maximum levels columns.